# Not able to iterate over Map objects in Firefox console: undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox

Still new to Javascript.

I tried iterating over a Map object and printing the keys/values in the console. However it just returns undefined, even if I use the example from the Mozilla firefox documentation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

eg,

```
const myMap = new Map()
myMap.set(0, 'zero')
myMap.set(1, 'one')

for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
  console.log(key + ' = ' + value)
}
```

Does anybody know what might the problem here?

It seems to work on Chrome, but in Firefox console (Ubuntu VM) it only returns undefined.

[image: Screenshot of console that contains the code but no output.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled showing logs. Above the console, to the right of the filter there are buttons for different levels of messages you can enable or disable: **Errors**, **Warnings**, **Logs**, **Info**, **Debug**. All of these are currently disabled (toggled off) - you can recognise it by the white background.

The **Logs** also shows **(2)** which means that there are two log messages that have been filtered out from display:

[image: Screenshot of the console where the "Logs (2)" button is highlighted.]

You need to click on **Logs** to enable viewing the log messages. The background would change if it is enabled.